# Setting a timeout for socket operations

Tags: java, sockets

When I create a socket:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, port);
```

It throws an exception, which is OK, because the IP address is not available. (The test variables where `String ipAddress = "192.168.0.3"` and `int port = 300`.)

The problem is: how do I set it to timeout for that socket?

When I create the socket, how do I reduce the time before I get a `UnknownHostException` and get the socket to timeout?

Comment: @adrianboimvaser: In that case, you should flag as a duplicate, and leave a comment pointing to the duplicate, so a moderator can close it as such (you left that comment a year ago - perhaps you know that by now). I would cast my vote for doing that now, but i have no idea where the duplicate is!

Comment: To continue the trend of replying years late, @EJP the title of this question is much less ambiguous than the duplicate you suggested

Comment: @Isaac And in fact it isn't a duplicate at all, comment retracted.

Comment: (Note: I have tweaked the tittle to be less ambiguous.)

Answer (score 179):

Use the [`Socket()` constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket%28%29), and [`connect(SocketAddress endpoint, int timeout)` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect%28java.net.SocketAddress%29) instead.

In your case it would look something like:

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ipAddress, port), 1000);
```

---

Quoting from the documentation

> `connect`
>
> ```
> public void connect(SocketAddress endpoint, int timeout) throws IOException
> ```
>
> Connects this socket to the server with a specified timeout value. A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout. The connection will then block until established or an error occurs.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `endpoint` - the SocketAddress
>    `timeout` - the timeout value to be used in milliseconds.
>
> **Throws:**
>
> `IOException` - if an error occurs during the connection 
>    `SocketTimeoutException` - if timeout expires before connecting 
>    `IllegalBlockingModeException` - if this socket has an associated channel, and the channel is in non-blocking mode 
>     `IllegalArgumentException` - if endpoint is null or is a SocketAddress subclass not supported by this socket
>
> Since:
>          1.4

Comment: This can reduce the timeout for ConnectException (but not increase it), and it has no effect on the timeout for UnknownHostException, which the OP claims he is getting (although I don't believe it). Note also that the Javadoc is incorrect in stating that the default is infinity. It isn't. The platform has a default timeout of around a minute, and this cannot be increased.

Comment: Even after 4 years this was helpful, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: It is now after 5 years and it is the best answer i found on Internet .. Thank you

Comment: It's also important to call `socket.setSoTimeout(timeoutMillis)` for timeouts during blocking IO operations.

Answer (score 47):

You don't set a timeout for the socket, you set a timeout for the *operations* you perform on that socket.

For example `socket.connect(otherAddress, timeout)`

Or `socket.setSoTimeout(timeout)` for setting a timeout on `read()` operations.

See:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html

Comment: Well, in this case it is also an operation, connecting. I can not find any place that states that this ctor uses an infinite timeout although that seems to be the case.

Comment: @sandos It is clearly stated in the Javadoc for connect(). However it is also incorrect. The default timeout is the platform timeout, around a minute, not infinity, and it can only be reduced by this connect() method, not increased.

Comment: note, `socket.setSoTimeout` must be called AFTER `connect`, or it will have no effect and reads will never time out. this is one poorly documented gotcha.

Answer (score 21):

You could use the following solution:

```
SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(ip, port);
// Create your socket
Socket socket = new Socket();
// Connect with 10 s timeout
socket.connect(sockaddr, 10000);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: If, as he claims, he is getting an UnknownHostException, it will happen on the first line, where there is no modified timeout in effect.

Comment: However, the first line doesn't throw any exception. From the documentation: "An attempt will be made to resolve the hostname into an InetAddress. If that attempt fails, the address will be flagged as unresolved"

Comment: In which case it will be resolved by the `connect()` method, but not under control of a timeout.

Answer (score 9):

You can't control the timeout due to `UnknownHostException`. These are DNS timings. You can only control the connect timeout given a valid host. None of the preceding answers addresses this point correctly.

But I find it hard to believe that you are really getting an `UnknownHostException` when you specify an IP address rather than a hostname.

**EDIT** To control Java's DNS timeouts [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21085015/207421).

Answer (score 8):

Use the [default constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket%28%29) for Socket and then use the [connect() method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect%28java.net.SocketAddress,%20int%29).

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to execute the DNS resolution on a different thread which is given only a certain amount of time to complete.

Here's a simple utility that can help you do this:

```
public class TimeSliceExecutor {

  public static class TimeSliceExecutorException extends RuntimeException {
    public TimeSliceExecutorException(String message, Throwable cause) {
      super(message, cause);
    }
  }

  public static void execute(Runnable runnable, long timeoutInMillis) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    try {
      Future<?> future = executor.submit(runnable);
      getFuture(future, timeoutInMillis);
    }
    finally {
      if (executor != null) {
        executor.shutdown();
      }
    }
  }

  public static <T> T execute(Callable<T> callable, long timeoutInMillis) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    try {
      Future<T> future = executor.submit(callable);
      return getFuture(future, timeoutInMillis);
    }
    finally {
      if (executor != null) {
        executor.shutdown();
      }
    }
  }

  public static <T> T getFuture(Future<T> future, long timeoutInMillis) {
    try {
      return future.get(timeoutInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      throw new TimeSliceExecutorException("Interrupton exception", ex);
    }
    catch (ExecutionException ex) {
      throw new TimeSliceExecutorException("Execution exception", ex);
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex) {
      throw new TimeSliceExecutorException(String.format("%dms timeout reached", timeoutInMillis), ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Then build the socket along these lines:

```
private Socket buildSocket() throws IOException {
  final Socket socket = new Socket();
  socket.setSoTimeout(socketTimeout);
  socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(resolveHost(host, dnsTimeout), port), connectionTimeout);
  return socket;
}

private static InetAddress resolveHost(String host, long dnsTimeout) throws IOException {
  try {
    return TimeSliceExecutor.execute(() -> InetAddress.getByName(host), dnsTimeout);
  }
  catch (TimeSliceExecutor.TimeSliceExecutorException ex) {
    throw new UnknownHostException(host);
  }
}
```

*Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70610305/225217*