# Set timeout on Socket before it tries to connect

Tags: java, android, sockets

The Socket class documentation is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html).

In my code atm, I use a constructor that's like this:

`Socket m_Socket = new Socket(m_Address, m_Port);`

`m_Address` is an InetAddress and `m_Port` is an int.

When this line runs, and the socket cannot be made, the app waits 3 seconds or so before throwing an IOException.

I can see there is no constructor that takes both `InetAddress`, `int`, **and** another `int` for timeout. I need to wait 250ms and not ~3 seconds as it is now. This means that I need to set the timeout on the socket, but I cannot find any method to do this. I know we have the method `setSoTimeout(timeout)`, but it needs to be called on an instance of the `Socket` class. I can instantiate a new Socket by doing this: `m_Socket = new Socket();`, but then I'd need to set the InetAddress and port, and the Socket class does not seem to have any methods for doing this (except for the constructor).

How do I set the timeout before it actually tries to set the socket?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969760/set-timeout-for-socket

Comment: The default connect timeout is over a minute, not 3 seconds, and 250ms is an absurdly short connect timeout value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create an unconnected Socket with the default constructor and then call connect() with timeout.

```
Socket m_Socket = new Socket();
m_Socket.connect(addr,1000);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Had to convert my InetAddress to a SocketAddress firstly.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
    Socket sock  = new Socket();
    sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress(m_Address, m_Port), 250);
```