# Java Socket connecting and suddenly disconnecting

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, disconnect

I have a Java application that needs to connect to IP 10.2.200.12 , port 3002. In this application i send some data to this host and receive its answer, then i close the connection. The problem is I connect to this address but some seconds after my connection is falling.
I try connecting using Hercules, and in the log appeared this messagges

Connecting to 10.2.200.12...
Connected  to 10.2.200.12
And some seconds later...
Connection Closed

In my application (client) i connect using this

```
String ip="10.2.200.12"
int port=3002
Socket s=new Socket(ip,port)
```

Some ideas?? I need to establish connection so i can send data and receive it...
Thankss

Comment: This is most likely your connection timing out. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969760/set-timeout-for-socket).

Comment: Better put a debug point at server code to see what's happening, bcoz connection is closed after its established.

Comment: Is the connection closed *before* or *after* you sent some data? - What does your client do after successful connection?

Comment: I cant debug at server code, because I dont have access to it, but i will try establishing connection as Hanno explains.

Comment: Sorry, as M0skit0 explained

Comment: Under what circumstances are you logging 'connection closed'?

Comment: @m0skit0 How can it be most likely a connect timeout when he has logged 'connected'?

Comment: @EJP sorry, I misunderstood the question. Try to connect with [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) and see what happens.