# URLConnection.setConnectTimeout() does not work when DNS is unreachable

Tags: java

Here is my code :

```
URL u = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(3000);
        conn.connect();
```

My network connection is sometimes unstable(I've connected to the wireless router but actually my router doesn't have Internet access). When that happens, this code will block for a lone time and finally throws `UnknownHostException`. Why `setConnectTimeout(3000)` doesn't work in this case? How to fix this?
Thanks!

------------update---------------

My guess is that `conn.connect()` will query DNS first but there's no time limit for this operation. I've tried `Socket` class and problem remains. `setTimeout()` seems do not work for DNS query.

Comment: @fge `u.openConnection()` does not establish the connection to server until    `conn.connect()` is called

Comment: This answer might work, but I haven't tested it. Seems to suggest you can set the DNS timeout on a per-domain basis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084830/how-to-set-the-timeout-for-socket-when-looking-for-host/21085015#21085015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a post that can work around it. Use another thread to query DNS to simulate timeout:
http://thushw.blogspot.sg/2009/11/resolving-domain-names-quickly-with.html

Answer (score 0):

Some non-standard implmentation of this method may ignore the specified timeout. 
See this [setConnectTimeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout(int))

Comment: I've noted that. But I'm using Oracle's HotSpot JVM, it doesn't seem like a non-standard implementation.

Comment: can you try set ConnectTimeout by 1, it throws SocketTimeoutException sometimes and UnknownHostException others. It means ConnectTimeout  works.