# SocketTimeoutException at 5 seconds - Any way to increase?

Tags: google-app-engine

The server i'm hitting is responding at 5.5 seconds regularly but I'm getting a SocketTimeoutException at 5 seconds even. Is there a way to increase this value? Will upgrading to a paid tier allow me this ability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/#Fetching_URLs_with_java_net

In particular

> You can set a deadline for a request, the most amount of time the
>   service will wait for a response. By default, the deadline for a fetch
>   is 5 seconds. The maximum deadline is 60 seconds for HTTP requests and
>   10 minutes for task queue and cron job requests. When using the
>   URLConnection interface, the service uses the connection timeout
>   (setConnectTimeout()) plus the read timeout (setReadTimeout()) as the
>   deadline.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't tagged your question with any language, so I'll try to cover the ones that I know.

*I haven't tested any of these in production, only on development.*

### Python

Seems to support the [setdefaulttimeout](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/remote_socket/_remote_socket.py?r=367#389) method. You can pass in number of **seconds** as a `float` or `int`:

```
import socket

socket.setdefaulttimeout(10)

# create socket connections as usual…
```

### Java

The [socket documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/) claims that it natively supports [java.net.Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html). According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4969788/252239), you can specify the timeout in **milliseconds**, like this (10 seconds):

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ipAddress, port), 10000);
```

### Go

Using [socket.DialTimeout](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/sockets/reference#DialTimeout) instead of [socket.Dial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/sockets/reference#Dial) you can specify the timeout as a [time.Duration](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) object (i.e. **nanoseconds**).

```
import (
    // …
    "appengine/socket"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    conn, err := socket.DialTimeout(c, "tcp", "myhost.com:1234", 10*time.Second)
    // …
}
```

---

Note that the timeout *may include name resolution*, if you connect to a hostname rather than a bare IP. There might also be an upper limit that is not language-specific, but it isn't documented.