# Volley sending multiple requests

Tags: android, android-volley, retrypolicy

I am using volley library in my android project to interact with the server. However, when the internet connection is slow and the request has been already made, volley retries the request one more time. Although, I have already set defaultRetryPolicy as:

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    10000, 0,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

It does not seem to work for me.

Please suggest something.

Comment: Try this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457952/how-to-have-a-reliable-volley-request-with-no-retries-policy