# SocketTimeoutException while read from stream

Tags: java, sockets

I have Socket stream and I need to use `in.read()` from stream function even if no data available.

I need this approach because blocking `read` function raises exception if the socket is disconnected and this is the only way to know if socket is alive.

I found that `in.read()` is waiting for data for approximately 2 min. and raises `SocketTimeoutException` if no data is available.

Can I somehow set read from socket timeout value?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969760/set-timeout-for-socket

Comment: The following statements in your question are mistaken: (1) 'blocking `read()` function raises exception if the socket is disconnected', and (2) '`in.read()` is waiting for approximately 2 min`. The fact is that a blocking mode read blocks forever unless (1) the connection has been reset, (2) the peer has disconnected or (3) you have set a read timeout. 'Can I somehow set read from socket timeout value?' is meaningless. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the Socket's KeepAlive() function as follows:

```
s = new Socket(serverIP, portOut);
s.setKeepAlive(true);
```

This will cause the socket to (obviously) keep itself alive and will not timeout.

You can also increase the timeout parameter by:

```
s.setSoTimeout(time_in_milliseconds);
```

Comment: Untrue. If the peer doesn't send anything within the read timeout period, the read will timeout, keepalive or no keepalive.

Answer (score -1):

Just set the SO_TIMEOUT on your Java Socket using:

```
socket.setSoTimeout(30*1000);
```

Timeout above is set in milliseconds

With this option set to a non-zero timeout, a read() call on the InputStream associated with this Socket will block for only this amount of time. On Expiry, SocketTimeoutException is raised.

Comment: That is his *problem.* Not the solution.

Comment: Well his question ends with how to set timeout on sockets for read operation? This response is correct to that extent. But if you are suggesting why he is getting exception while blocking to read. That is a different problem. He needs to check if it is due to read returning less than 0 (error) or 0 bytes hinting the connection is reset by peer.

Comment: The question reports a problem with unexpected socket timeouts. The reason can only be that he is already setting a read timeout. If he wasn't, there wiould be no timeout: the read would block forever. `read()` can't return < 0 or zero *and* throw an exception at the same time, and zero does not 'hint that the connection has been reset' by anybody, including the peer.

Comment: That makes sense. Agreed.