# How to set SSL Socket Connection Time Out in java

Tags: sockets, ssl, connection, timeout

Can any one help me in setting the connection time out in java. I have this piece of code.

SSLSocket sslSocket = new SSLSocket(host, port, context);
sslSocket.startHandshake();

I know that there is a line which we can add before stating hand shake sslSocket.setSoTimeout(timeout) but as far as i heard setSoTimeout is applicable both for both connection and read time out. I just want for connection time out but not for read time out. In detail, i just want time out if hand shake didnt happen in 10sec. Once hand shake happened, no time out must happen until i get response

Can any one please help me

Comment: Please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4969788/836507

Comment: Using default constructor socket(), can we set the Context parameter ? context parameter is basically for X509 certificate.

Comment: You can specify connection timeout in connect() call

Comment: connect () method just accepts parms InetAddress and timeout. I am not having option to set  the SSLClient Context in connect() method.

Comment: First you create SSLSocket with the constructor where you pass the context. Then you call its connect() method with the desired timeout

Comment: Socket socket = new Socket();
    SSLSocket sslSocket = new SSLSocket(socket, aSslClientContext);
    sslSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host,port),10000);
    sslSocket.startHandshake();

Does this work?