# Java socket wait more than 1min to try connect with server

Tags: java, sockets

Socket requestSocket = new Socket(a, 6666);

When I try to connect with serwer and server is unavailable I gave to wait 1 min or more to see  ja

```
va.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.43.50 (port 6666): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
09-14 08:36:02.705 3244-3345/net.simplifiedcoding.navigationdrawerexample W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
```

How can I set lower time to try connect with server ?

Comment: you can set a timeout on connect read this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969760/setting-a-timeout-for-socket-operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969760/setting-a-timeout-for-socket-operations)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're using [Socket.connect(SocketAddress)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect(java.net.SocketAddress)) method. There is another [Socket.connect(SocketAddress, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect(java.net.SocketAddress,%20int)) where you can specify timeout as the second parameter. Hope it helps!