# How to get around Kotlin TCP Socket() call that is blocking

Tags: android, kotlin, sockets, tcp

My Android/Kotlin application connects to a TCP server.
Usually these three lines of code serve me well:

```
client1 = Socket(SERVER_IP_ADDRESS, SERVER_IP_PORT)
output1 = DataOutputStream (client1.getOutputStream())
input1 = DataInputStream (client1.getInputStream())
```

However, today the server is down and now I can see that the code hangs forever on the first line:

```
client1 = Socket(SERVER_IP_ADDRESS, SERVER_IP_PORT)
```

Can someone suggest any relatively easy way around this (I am an Android/Kotlin beginner)?

Thanks in advance

Garrett

***** UPDATE *****

Thanks to @useruser207421 and to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969760/setting-a-timeout-for-socket-operations), I am nearly there

My code now looks like this:

```
try {
  client1 = Socket()
  client1.connect(InetSocketAddress(SERVER_IP_ADDRESS, SERVER_IP_PORT), 3000)
  output1 = DataOutputStream (client1.getOutputStream())
  input1 = DataInputStream (client1.getInputStream())
} catch (ex : Exception) {
  // do something
} finally {
  // do something
}
```

However, the client1.connect() call does NOT timeout after the specified 3 seconds.

If the exception is a DNS error, it will fail immediately with

```
java.net.UnknownHostException
```

which is good.

However, the server was down earlier, and I am not sure what the exception was, but the exception was generated after 20 seconds, not 3.

So I will have to keep an eye on this - presumably I have got most, but not all, of the logic right.

Comment: Set a read timeout to some reasonable value, and catch the resulting `SocketTimeoutException`.

Comment: @user207421, thank you - that has got me nearly there - see my update

Comment: Set a connect timeout on the socket before you call connect.